# How to call parent activity function from ASyncTask finish

Tags: android

I have a MainActivity and an AsyncTask class. MainActivity works well when I call this myTask.

But how to call myTask's onPostExecute result from MainActivity.

This is my first question, I apologize if I'm wrong.

myTask class

```
public  class myTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
    DownloadCallback mDownloadCallback;
    Exception mException;
    Context mContext;
    JSONArray PHPfromArray= null;
    String status="", message="";
    private OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();


    public myTask(Context context, DownloadCallback downloadCallback) {
        mContext = context;
        mDownloadCallback = downloadCallback;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(mContext);
        mProgressDialog.setMessage("Downloading.. ");
        mProgressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... p) {
        String jsonData = null;

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        if ( result== null )
        {
            mDownloadCallback.onFailure(mException);
        } else {
            mDownloadCallback.onSuccess(durum);
        }
    }



    public interface DownloadCallback
    {
        void onSuccess(String downloadedString);
        void onFailure(Exception exception);
    }
}
```

This code does not work, how to call from MainActivity?

```
   new myTask(this, new myTask() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(String downloadedString) {

            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Exception exception) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: You have forget to call execute() method. I am edited your question.

Comment: Can you describe what your task is and what you want to do exactly when the task runs and when it finishes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could modify `myTask` like this:

```
  ....
  public myTask(Context context){
            mContext = context;
  }//firstly modify constructor

  public void setCallback(DownloadCallback downloadCallback){
        mDownloadCallback = downloadCallback;
  }//add a function
  ...
```

Then you could implements the android in activity like below:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements myTask.DownloadCallback {
            ...
            final myTask myTask = new myTask(MainActivity.this);
            myTask.setCallback(MainActivity.this);
            myTask.execute();

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(String downloadedString) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Exception exception) {

            }
        }
```